# If variable equals multiple strings in a navigation list

Tags: php, variables, navigation, if-statement, operators

I found something similar to this question but it wasn't related to strings. I'm just looking for the best way to write the following code, I figured there has to be some short version I don't know about.

```
<ul id="top-nav">
    <li <?php if($filename == "index.php"){echo ("class=\"current\"");} ?>><a href="index.php" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li <?php if($filename == "cause.php"){echo ("class=\"current\"");} ?>><a href="cause.php" title="Cause">Cause</a></li>
    <li><a href="order.php" title="Order">Order</a></li>
    <li class="drop-down<?php if($filename == "grand-prize-one.php" | $filename == "grand-prize-two.php"){echo (" current");} ?>"><a href="grand-prize-one.php" title="Grand Prizes">Grand Prizes</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="grand-prize-one.php" title="Grand Prize One">Grand Prize One</a></li>
        <li><a href="grand-prize-two.php" title="Grand Prize Two">Grand Prize Two</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li <?php if($filename == "early-bird.php"){echo ("class=\"current\"");} ?>><a href="early-bird.php" title="Early Bird">Early Bird</a></li>
    <li class="drop-down<?php if($filename == "vehicles.php" || $filename == "vacations.php" || $filename == "other-prizes.php"){echo (" current");} ?>"><a href="vehicles.php" title="Electronics &amp; more">Other Prizes</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="vehicles.php" title="Vehicles">Vehicles</a></li>
        <li><a href="vacations.php" title="Vacations">Vacations</a></li>
        <li><a href="other-prizes.php" title="Electronics &amp; more">Electronics &amp; more</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li <?php if($filename == "winners.php"){echo ("class=\"current\"");} ?>><a href="winners.php" title="Winners">Winners</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Is there a shorter way to write `$filename == "vehicles.php" || $filename == "vacations.php" || $filename == "other-prizes.php"`? I doubt I'd ever need it to accommodate more the 5-10 possible strings.

Thank you

**SOLUTION**

For those who find this question, I ended up doing this:

*With my main PHP*

```
<?php
 // My other code
 $grandPrizes = array("grand-prize-one.php","grand-prize-two.php");
 $otherPrizes = array("vehicles.php","vacations.php","other-prizes.php");
?>
```

*My inline PHP in the li element*

```
<?php if (in_array($filename, $grandPrizes)) {echo " current";} ?>
```

Comment: Please use || instead of | for or-comparisons.

Comment: || is a logical operator, | is a bitwise operator

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you. I had no idea. I don't know where I got that from but it's always worked for me. Just curious, why does it work?

Comment: The logical operator will return true if either $a or $b is true (`$a || $b`). The bitwise operator will return the bits that are set in either $a or $b (`$a | $b`). If the returned bits do not equal zero, they will equal to `true` (if you are not using the `===` or `!==` operator).

Comment: By the way, you do not have to use brackets for using echo (`echo (" current");` => `echo " current";`.

Comment: Oh thanks Michiel. I had a feeling this question would bring out the faults in my PHP knowledge.

Comment: I think that solution part was pretty nice, it doesn't copy the answer to the question but still adds value to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$filenames = array("vehicles.php","vacations.php","other-prizes.php");
if (in_array($filename, $filenames)) {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a switch:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

```
switch($filename) {
    case "vehicles.php":
    case "vacations.php":
    case "other-prizes.php":
        echo "class=\"current\"";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You could use**

```
if(in_array($filename, array("vehicles.php", "vacations.php", "other-prizes.php"))){
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    if(in_array($filename, array("vehicles.php", "vacations.php", "other-prizes.php")) {
        echo ("class=\"current\"");
    } 
?>
```

[in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function is appropriate for what you are trying to do.